# How to add hours to unix timestamp miliseconds?

Tags: javascript

The users in the app can select time and duration of appointment. I would like to add duration to time to show them end time. I handle everything in milliseconds in the background and convert it back to the user in hours with a function. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong because in the example, the console prints 01:00. I think it should print `16:00`.

Here a hardcoded waterdown version of the codes:

```js
var date = '2021-02-12';
var start_time = '15:00';//24hour format
var total_hours = '3600000';//total hours from hidden input in miliseconds//3600000 = 1hour
var miliseconds = new Date(date + ' ' + start_time).getMilliseconds();//convert datetime to mili

//add hours to start time to get end time
var end_time = parseInt(miliseconds) + parseInt(total_hours);

console.log(msToTime(end_time));

function msToTime(duration) {
var milliseconds = parseInt((duration % 1000) / 100),
seconds = Math.floor((duration / 1000) % 60),
minutes = Math.floor((duration / (1000 * 60)) % 60),
hours = Math.floor((duration / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24);

hours = (hours < 10) ? "0" + hours : hours;
minutes = (minutes < 10) ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
seconds = (seconds < 10) ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

return hours + ":" + minutes ;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Local timezone issue.   This provide the `16:00` you are looking for.

```
var date = '2021-02-12';
var start_time = '15:00';//24hour format
var total_hours = '3600000';//total hours from hidden input in miliseconds//3600000 = 1hour
var miliseconds = Date.parse(date + 'T' + start_time + ':00.000Z');//convert datetime to mili

//add hours to start time to get end time
var end_time = parseInt(miliseconds) + parseInt(total_hours);

console.log(msToTime(end_time));

function msToTime(duration) {
    var milliseconds = parseInt((duration % 1000) / 100),
    seconds = Math.floor((duration / 1000) % 60),
    minutes = Math.floor((duration / (1000 * 60)) % 60),
    hours = Math.floor((duration / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24);

    hours = (hours < 10) ? "0" + hours : hours;
    minutes = (minutes < 10) ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
    seconds = (seconds < 10) ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

    return hours + ":" + minutes ;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why aren't you just using the already-defined `Date` object?

***Actum Ne Agas:*** *"Do Not Do A Thing Already Done.™"*

Comment: Is this not what I'm already doing? new Date(date + ' ' + start_time).getMilliseconds();

Comment: I think he means to use `new Date(duration)` in the `msToTime()` function.

Answer (score 0):

`.getMilliseconds()` returns the milliseconds part of the date, not the entire date in milliseconds (just as `.getHourse()` returns the hour part of the date).

The method to get the time in milliseconds is [`.getTime()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime). So use

```
var miliseconds = new Date(date + ' ' + start_time).getTime();
```

You can also use this value when converting back to a time, since the `Date()` constructor accepts a time in milliseconds.

```
function msToTime(duration) {
    var d = new Date(duration);
    var hours = d.getHours();
    var minutes = d.getMinutes();

    return hours + ":" + minutes ;
}
```

Comment: I had a restless night. Second pairs of eyes is much appreciated. But getTime() , returns 21:00? 1hour from 15:00 should return 4:00PM (16:00)

Comment: That might be a timezone issue.

Comment: Then this is not a portable solution.

Comment: See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#date_format_and_time_zone_conversions

Comment: Yes im aware. That's what I want to avoid. I just want to treat this as a simple math calculation independent of any timezone issues.

Comment: Just make sure you consistently use local or UTC methods and it should work.

Comment: Cant I just bypass the headaches?  15 + 1 = 16. Nice and easy and returns correct answer every single time.

Comment: I think the problem may be occurring when you do `new Date(date + ' ' + start_time)`.

Comment: What's your suggestion?